# MobileFirst Platform - 2nd App Deployed in MFP Server having device authentication issue

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I have 2 apps deployed in our MFP server (*see attached screenshot*). The 1st app is working fine but the 2nd app is having issue during launch wherein device authentication is failing. In xcode console, error I am getting is 'DeviceAuth: Can't find variable: require'

On the MFP console, I can see that both apps are sharing the list of devices provisioned.

Question is, are we allowed to deploy more than 1 app in an MFP server using the same configuration DB?

The reason for having 2 separate app is we want to maintain the 1st app as BAU and the 2nd app is for the next phase of the project.

Thank you n advance.

[MFP Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2T7u.png)

[Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Staq4.png)

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be fixed by eliminating/avoiding same identification of the apps namely; App Id, Display Name and Bundle Id... these entries cannot be identical on both apps.

Answer (score 0):

The error you've provided on its own is not enough... if the app is not working, then provide server logs and clients logs, explain when and how it is failing and so on...

> Question is, are we allowed to deploy more than 1 app in an MFP server using the same configuration DB?

The MobileFirst Server is capable of handling multiple runtimes - as can be seen in your screen shot. You have two runtimes, each with its own app.

Comment: The is the log I am getting from Xcode console.

"Error in Success callbackId: DeviceAuth947271104 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require"

The strange thing is that, the other app (mpma) from my screenshot is working well.

Comment: And now to the when and how... a specific request? On startup? Any interaction between the apps? You need to explain the scenario.

Comment: The error is happening at startup. It only stays on the splash screen. One thing I noticed is that, on the console, when I open the devices tab under app mpma2, the device still attached to the first app (mpma). Not sure how MFP manage this part but I suspect that is the cause of the issue that is why I am getting failed during device authentication. See new image attached top (Devices).

Comment: If the apps share the same identifications, it could be that this prevents one from working... Try changing the app ID for one of them?

Comment: App IDs are different, the other one called 'mpma' and other is 'mpma2', if you are referring to the app Id in the application-descriptor.xml. But both having the same 'Display Name'. Is there any impact on this?

Comment: I'm almost certain it's because something between them is too identical... what happens if you remove the first and keep only the second?

Comment: I've changed the Display Name and Bundle Id. Not sure which of them fix the issue but it works. I can now see a new entry on the device list tagged under the 2nd app. Thanks

Comment: Do you mind writing this as an answer to the question please?